# hibernate is updating in the middle of selects

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a legacy web app that I am maintaining. It started out as Java 1.4, but I've compiled it to Java5. We're using Spring+Hibernate. I'm not using annotations yet. I'm sticking with XDoclet for now. In it, I have an object graph that looks like this:

Job 1:m Operations 1:m Activities 1:m Transactions

Those Transactions are *NOT* J2EE transactions. We're just documenting the workflow from one Activity to another.

In HttpRequest#1, I update a couple of Activities and create a new Transaction. Then in HttpRequest#2, I redisplay the entire Job. What I am seeing at this point is the usual SELECT statements for the Job, Operations and Activities, but then I'm seeing some UPDATE statements for the Transactions. It turns out those updates are reverting the Transactions back to their previous states, discarding the latest updates.

Why in the world is Hibernate doing this?

As requested, here's the .hbm.xml file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="ActivityTransaction" table="imed_if_move_transactions"
    lazy="false" mutable="true">
    <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
    <id name="id" column="IF_MOVE_TRANSACTION_ID" type="java.lang.Long">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">IMED_IF_MOVE_TRANSACTIONS_S</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="activityActionKey" type="java.lang.String"
      update="true" insert="true" column="ACTIVITY_ACTION_KEY" />
    <property name="approvalStatus" type="int" update="true"
      insert="true" column="APPROVAL_STATUS" />
    <property name="authorizedBy" type="java.lang.Long" update="true"
      insert="true" column="AUTHORIZATION_ID" />
    <many-to-one name="authorizedByUser"
      class="UserModel" cascade="none"
      outer-join="false" update="false" insert="false" not-found="ignore"
      fetch="select" column="AUTHORIZATION_ID" />
    <property name="date" type="java.util.Date" update="true"
      insert="true" column="JOA_TRANSACTION_DATE" />
    <many-to-one name="from"
      class="JobOpActivity" cascade="none"
      outer-join="false" update="true" insert="true" fetch="select"
      column="FM_JOB_OP_ACTIVITY_ID" />
    <property name="fromIntraActivityStepType" type="java.lang.Integer"
      update="true" insert="true" column="FM_INTRAACTIVITY_STEP_TYPE" />
    <property name="fromIntraOperationStepType" type="java.lang.Integer"
      update="true" insert="true" column="FM_INTRAOPERATION_STEP_TYPE" />
    <property name="fromOperationSeqNum" type="java.lang.Integer"
      update="true" insert="true" column="FM_OPERATION_SEQ_NUM" />
    <many-to-one name="job" class="Job"
      cascade="none" outer-join="false" update="true" insert="true" fetch="select"
      column="WIP_ENTITY_ID" />
    <property name="operationEndDate" type="java.util.Date"
      update="true" insert="true" column="OP_END_DATE" />
    <property name="operationStartDate" type="java.util.Date"
      update="true" insert="true" column="OP_START_DATE" />
    <many-to-one name="organization" class="Organization"
      cascade="none" outer-join="false" update="true" insert="true" fetch="select"
      column="ORGANIZATION_ID" />
    <property name="processingStatus" type="java.lang.String"
      update="true" insert="true" column="PROCESS_FLAG" />
    <property name="quantity" type="int" update="true" insert="true"
      column="TRANSACTION_QUANTITY" />
    <property name="reasonId" type="java.lang.Long" update="true"
      insert="true" column="REASON_ID" />
    <property name="reference" type="java.lang.String" update="true"
      insert="true" column="REFERENCE" />
    <property name="scrapAccountId" type="java.lang.Long" update="true"
      insert="true" column="SCRAP_ACCOUNT_ID" />
    <property name="spsaId" type="java.lang.Long" update="true"
      insert="true" column="SPSA_ID" />
    <many-to-one name="to"
      class="JobOpActivity" cascade="none"
      outer-join="false" update="true" insert="true" fetch="select"
      column="TO_JOB_OP_ACTIVITY_ID" />
    <property name="toIntraActivityStepType" type="java.lang.Integer"
      update="true" insert="true" column="TO_INTRAACTIVITY_STEP_TYPE" />
    <property name="toIntraOperationStepType" type="java.lang.Integer"
      update="true" insert="true" column="TO_INTRAOPERATION_STEP_TYPE" />
    <property name="toOperationSeqNum" type="java.lang.Integer"
      update="true" insert="true" column="TO_OPERATION_SEQ_NUM" />
    <property name="typeId" type="java.lang.Long" update="true"
      insert="true" column="TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID" />
    <property name="webKeyEntryId" type="java.lang.String"
      update="true" insert="true" column="WEB_KEY_ENTRY_ID" />
    <property name="issueMaterial" type="true_false" update="true"
      insert="true" column="MATERIAL_ISSUE" />
    <property name="createDate" type="java.util.Date" update="true"
      insert="true" column="CREATION_DATE" />
    <property name="createdBy" type="java.lang.Integer" update="true"
      insert="true" column="CREATED_BY" />
    <property name="lastUpdateDate" type="java.util.Date" update="true"
      insert="true" column="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
    <property name="lastUpdatedBy" type="java.lang.Integer"
      update="true" insert="true" column="LAST_UPDATED_BY" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And here's an example transaction setup:

```
<bean id="moldingActivitiesService" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="transactionManager" ref="etrack2ProviderTransactionManager"/>
  <property name="target" ref="moldingActivitiesServiceTarget"/>
  <property name="transactionAttributes">
    <props>
      <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you post the source code of the Transactions entity (with the annotations or the equivalent entries from hbm.xml)? I suspect that in your object graph, the Transactions entity is the only that is employing lazy fetching for its non-collection properties.

Comment: Ah, lazy fetching for "non-collection properties"? No, we don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally found the problem. Here's a more complete flow:

I have Controller C1, Manager M1, Manager M2 and Persister P1. M1 and M2 have managed transactions as I stated above, using TransactionProxyFactoryBean.

- C1.methodA() calls M1.methodB() which calls P1.methodC()
- C1.methodA() then calls M2.methodD(), which then calls M1.methodE() which calls P1.methodF().

See the problem yet?

It happens when M1.methodD calls M1.methodE(). What I think happens is that since both M1 and M2 are transaction managed, two transactions are created, one for each call. Those two transactions battle it out for which one has the true state of the system, with neither one truly winning.

Answer (score 2):

From some Hibernate Javadoc document on Google http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html:

> **AUTO**

```
public static final FlushMode AUTO
```

> The Session is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to ensure that queries never return stale state. This is the default flush mode.

Every modification you are doing on a JPA-managed entity is done in a persistent context. That means Hibernate is assuming that the things that you modify in your entity are safe to be committed. So when you select data from the same entity or related entities, in this mode Hibernate puts consistency of your changes over everything else. So it flushes and then does the read to reflect your changes correctly. If you do not want to have this behavior you can do two things:

- disable auto-commit (which I prefer, but it is some kind of a JPA convention, so make up your mind). The downside of this approach is that you have to do more by hand depending on your configuration. The upside is, that everything is much more explicit and less magic
- change your code that you collect the data you need first. Also this would make your code much cleaner. Because it would work like the basic computer science pattern everybody understands: Input, Computation, Output. Your mixing those things up, which is the reason why the default mode does not work.

Edit: On how to use Spring's PlatformTransactionManager best without using annotations I would recommend the TransactionTemplate: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-prog-template
Just inject your PlatformTransactionManager (Hibernate) there and use it to abstract from the transaction handling.

Comment: What I didn't mention was that the updates are during one HttpRequest and the selects are part of the next HttpRequest. Does that make a difference? Hibernate should have done a flush by then, right?

Comment: Our architecture is three layers, controller/manager/persister, with the managers under transaction control using Spring's TransactionProxyFactoryBean.

Comment: Ok, that helps. So how are you using that factory bean? Which TransactionManager do you use? Are you using annotations to define transaction boundaries?

Comment: We're using org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager. We're not using annotations (this is a legacy app), we're using XDoclet with some merge files. I'll add the XML for this up in the main question.

Comment: So legacy means older Java than 5? Otherwise I'd recommend you this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767065/why-doesnt-my-springhibernatetransactionmanager-work-in-wicket

Comment: I added a way to my post to do transactions with Spring w/o annotations

Comment: It started out in Java 1.4 but I've recompiled it to Java5. 
As to the reference to the other page, were you referring to "current_session_context_class" ? We don't use that.
I'll look at the stuff that you added in your edit.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your FLUSHMODE you will see this, because whenever you do a query, hibernate will normally guess as to whether it should FLUSH to get a clean and consistent read.

Comment: The flush mode is whatever the default is. We haven't changed it.